# Bespoke `proof` environment produces big vertical space just after a subsection title

Tags: environments, proof-package

I am using a bespoke document class which I have not developed. As part of this class, the `proof` environment is defined as follows:

```latex
\newenvironment{proof}{%
\par\addvspace{12pt plus3pt minus3pt}\global\logotrue%
\noindent{\bf Proof.\hskip.5em}\ignorespaces}{%
    \par\iflogo\vskip-\lastskip
    \vskip-\baselineskip\prbox\par
    \addvspace{12pt plus3pt minus3pt}\fi}
```

A few things are going there which I am not sure I follow. Among other things, I am not sure I even understand the need to redefine the `proof` environment (maybe the native one did not exist at the time this template was created?).

In any case, my question is with regards to the second line in the definition, starting with `\par...`. This seems to break a line and add vertical space; however when I start a `proof` environment just after a `subsection`, this creates a rather large space between the subsection title and the start of the `proof` environment.

I have tried removing that line, and it solves the issue. However, I am not sure what the point of the line is, and would like to avoid any unintended consequences in other instances of `proof`.

**What is the point of `\par\addvspace{12pt plus3pt minus3pt}\global\logotrue`, and is there an alternative which avoids the problem I have outlined?**

Comment: There is no `proof` environment defined in the LaTeX kernel and there has never been. Classes or packages can define it with `\newenvironment`. There is a `proof` environment defined in `amsthm`, but apparently your class doesn't load it. But as the question stands it's impossible to answer. By the way, the `\bf` command has been deprecated for about 30 years.

Comment: the line adds the maximum (not the sum) of the 12pt you show and whatever space is specified in your document class to follow a section heading. If that is bigger than you want change it, or better use a standard proof environment from `amsthm` (proof environments are normally designed to follow theorem enviornments not section headings so it is not that surprising if the default space is sub-optimal for you)

Comment: it is impossible to say what `\logotrue` does, it just sets some private boolean flag to true but how your code uses that you have not shown

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: actually the `\iflogo` is shown in the closing part of the `\newenvironment`. My guess is that the `\prbox` just sets the tombstone symbol at the end of the proof.

Comment: Searching on the intarwebs there are some templates from World Scientific that uses exactly this definition. Looking at *that* class file the purpose of the `\iflogo` flag is so that the author can issue `\prbox` in the proof to fine tune the location of the tombstone (similar in functionality to the `amsthm` `\qedhere`). But a weird side effect is that the tombstone will fail to print if you have _nested proofs_.

Comment: In those templates that I mentioned, you have `\def\prbox{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\phantom{\vrule width5pt height5pt depth0pt}}}\global\logofalse}`; note the `\global\logofalse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your document class has the following lines (to show a bit more definition beyond what you showed)

```
\newif\iflogo
\def\prbox{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\phantom{\vrule width5pt height5pt depth0pt}}}\global\logofalse}
%
\newenvironment{proof}{%
\par\addvspace{12pt plus3pt minus3pt}\global\logotrue%
\noindent{\bf Proof:\hskip.5em}\ignorespaces}{%
    \par\iflogo\vskip-\lastskip
    \vskip-\baselineskip\prbox\par
    \addvspace{12pt plus3pt minus3pt}\fi}
```

I will not tell you *what* to do, but tell you what the code does.

```
\newif\iflogo
```

Defines a new boolean flag.

```
\def\prbox{\hbox to \hsize{\hfill\fboxsep0pt\fbox{\phantom{\vrule width5pt height5pt depth0pt}}}\global\logofalse}
```

Defines the `\prbox` command. It has the following components (going backwards in this case since it is more convenient)

- at the end it sets `\global\logoflase` which sets the previously-defined boolean flag to false
- the `\fbox{...}` draws a framed box around a hidden (`\phantom`) rectangle (`\vrule`) that is 5pt by 5pt. The framed box has no padding (`\fboxsep0pt`). In effect, it draws an open square that is 5pt by 5pt
- the `\hfill` adds space before the box, so the box is flush right.

So altogether this makes a command that can be used to print the tombstone symbol at the end of the proof.

```
\newenvironment{proof}...
```

starts the definition of the proof environment. Remember that the two arguments are what goes before the start and what happens after the end.

```
{%
\par\addvspace{12pt plus3pt minus3pt}\global\logotrue%
\noindent{\bf Proof:\hskip.5em}\ignorespaces}
```

Starts a new paragraph. Increases (if necessary, as the material from before may have already added some vertical space) the vertical space to what happened before to 12pts (with some amount of glue).

The `\global\logotrue` sets the boolean flag to true, which is **important** when it comes to the second part of the definition. Then it prints the word `Proof` with appropriate spacing.

```
{%
    \par\iflogo\vskip-\lastskip
    \vskip-\baselineskip\prbox\par
    \addvspace{12pt plus3pt minus3pt}\fi}
```

Starts a new paragraph with `\par`. Then the `\iflogo` kicks in, if the boolean flag has been set to be true (as it has in the beginning of the proof environment), it will first cancel all the most recently added vertical spaces (effectively moving the cursor back up to the last line of the printed material). Then the `\prbox` happens to print the tombstone so that it shows on the right of the last printed line.
Then it ends the paragraph again and increase vertical space to 12pt so the beginning and end have symmetrical spacing.